# How to make a shiny panel on a matt texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, masking

[image]I'm wondering how I can add a shiny panel to the back of this object. I have a mask uploaded but am unsure of how to link the nodes up without undoing the other finishes on the material.

Any help much appreciated

Blend [here](https://we.tl/t-3DepLvWtAW).
Thanks guys.

Comment: is your new mask called "High Voltage Matt Laquer-01.png", if so, you have to plug it in the Factor of a Mix Shader that will mix the rest of your image and your shiny node (probably a glossy one).

Comment: It is indeed. Do you think you could edit the nodes, I've tried that but to no avail. Sorry for the noob questions...

Comment: The problem is, I'm not sure exactly what area you need to be shiny, so I'm not sure I can tell if your mask is correct. If you mix 2 nodes in a mix shader, let say one Diffuse and on Glossy, the black and white picture that you'll plug in the Factor of the mix will determine what part will be displayed as diffuse, and what other part will be displayed as shiny. If your picture has grey area you will have some parts with mix of diffuse and glossy. If the result is the inverse of what you want, just inverse the plugging of Diffuse and Glossy into the mix.

Comment: Its the areas in the (now attached) screenshot. I think I grasp the principle but I can't seem to get it to work without affecting the silvery flash on the front created by the principled node.

Comment: if it doesn't work it's because your nodes (and mask) organization is not good, hard to say where it is not as I don't know what you want

Comment: mmm I thought you were using a black and white mask but it's actually a alpha mask, so you should use the Image Texture Alpha output, but in that case your grey areas have no meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node organization will depend on the result you want. For example where exactly do you want to see shininess?

Anyway, as your mask has a big rectangle, let's imagine that you simply want to display a silver rectangle. As this rectangle is transparent and your mask image seems to play with transparency, and not black & white, it is made to use the Alpha output of the Image Texture node.

By the way, there are also grey areas on your mask, grey areas won't be useful if you play with the alpha channel, it will only be useful if you play with black & white, and therefore if you use the Color output of the Image Texture, and not the Alpha. In that case, if you want to use a B&W mask, your rectangle needs to be white.

So let's come back to our case: Just plug the Alpha output of your Image Texture node to the Factor of a Mix Shader. This node will mix your previous nodes organization and a new one, a Glossy, and a glossy rectangle will appear.

[image]